# Recreate BI's Edge in compositor?

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes

I've read that the Edge post processing effect from Blender Internal is Z based, and something similar can be done in the compositor. Can anyone suggest a setup for this, or have any ideas on how it would be done?

I'm looking for something other than Freestyle or BlenderNPR edge nodes. Scripting is fine.

Answer (score 4):

This probably isn't the answer you are looking for, but you could always render out using BI at the end of production, with a 'shadeless' white material applied in the render-layer settings as the material override (applies to all objects when rendered) Also, set the world colour as 100% white as well.

[image: renderlayer settings]

render result

[image: result render]

This would then allow you to composite the rendered image or sequence of images ontop of your cycles render, you can use a colour mix -> multiply so that only the black 'edge' is applied to the cycles render.

Comment: Thank you. This does work, but still not quite what I'm looking for. Even if I automate it, making another scene adds too much overhead.

Comment: Yeah I know what you mean. The more complicated the setup the more than can go wrong.  I guess the only other thing I could think of would be to research further specifically how the blender internal edge effect works, then you might be closer to finding a way to replicate it. Possibly contact the developer too,  it's all a lot of work though.

Answer (score 1):

There's an [excellent post](https://blendernpr.org/edge-node-v1-2-4-july-2015/) explaining how in details, on the excellent [BlenderNPR](https://blendernpr.org) with a .blend you can [download](https://blendernpr.org/downloads/) and use the node group in you own compositions.

Comment: Thanks! I am familiar with BlenderNPR edge nodes. It's based primarily on Filters, although it does use Z to some extent. But as far as I understand, it's very different functionally from Edge, and does not have the Threshold effect of Edge. Edge nodes is also fairly heavy, and difficult to get clean. I'm trying to reproduce Edge to have something a bit simpler, although it would be less powerful.

Comment: I assume you've already tried with freestyle too ?

Comment: Yep! Freestyle is the main thing I'm using, but it can't handle intersections. I'm looking for something to plug those gaps. Edge Nodes works for a lot of things, but requires you to to tweak it's settings for almost every frame, especially if things move a lot. Whereas Edge in BI gives clean and consistent results all the time, but I'm using Cycles.